# Finding functions orthogonal to all polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, orthogonal-polynomials

I think the title is correct, but I'm not familiar with this sort of question, so maybe it's off. Anyways, the question is

Find all real-valued $f$ that are continuous on $[0,1]$ and satisfy

$$\int_0^1f(x)x^n\, dx = 0, n = 0,1,2,\ldots$$

My first thought is that any functions that are $0$ on $[0,1]$ would work, but are there any other functions? I've seen this sort of problem before, but I don't know how to approach it.

Thanks.

Comment: You mean, that the integral equals zero, right?

Comment: Should that be equal to something?

Comment: Wow, ya forgot about that. Fixed now. Equal to zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Standard proof uses Weierstrass approximation theorem : any continuous function defined on closed interval $[a,b]$ can be uniformly approximated by polynomial. 
Using this, there exists sequence of polynomial $p_{n}(x)$ converges uniformly to $f(x)$ on $[0,1]$. By the assumption, we have $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)p_{n}(x)dx=0$ for all $n$ and uniformly convergence gives $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)^{2}dx=0$. Now we can derive $f\equiv 0$ by continuity of $f$.